# How do you setup the referrers for a google maps v3 key?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The website I am using is `test.herokuapp.com`.

The referer I've setup I've tried are:

```
http://test.herokuapp.com
test.herokuapp.com/*.
*.test.herokuapp.com/*.
test.herokuapp.com/
```

The error I get everytime is:

```
Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
test.herokuapp.com/*
```