# How to google maps api keys safe on website

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api-3, api-key

I am using the google maps api on my website and would like to use my API key, but I'm confused about how to keep it safe.  I know that I could just hardcode the actual key right into index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&key=HARDCODED_KEY"></script>
```

But then it's right there for anyone to see when they view the source code for the site. I also don't want it to show up in the DOM if someone's viewing the site with a debugging tool, like Firebug.

I'm assuming that there is a way to store it in a separate file (probably outside my html/ directory) that I can source.  If anyone could provide an example or comment on whether this approach would be relatively secure, I'd really appreciate the help.  I've found other posts on this topic, but none that apply for this (relatively simple) case.

Comment: The browser key is safe to display in you HTML (it has to be there and sent to the browser).  You need to set the referrers for the key so it only works on sites you own.

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks for the clarification.  I saw some documentation that warned against putting api keys directly in code, so I thought I needed a better solution.  But it sounds like as long as I set it up through the google developers console so that only my site can use the key, then it's secure even if it's hardcoded.  Cool :)

Answer (score 7):

Just set the referrers, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/places/auth):

> To prevent other applications from using your key and consuming your
>   quota, you can limit the IP addresses that can use your API key to
>   send requests:
>
> Visit the Google Developers Console and log in with your Google
>   account.
>
> Select the project that was created for you when you signed
>   up. The project name will start with Google Maps API for Work.
>
> In the
>   sidebar on the left, select Credentials.
>
> Find the key you're using
>   under the Public API Access heading, and click Edit allowed IPs.
>
> Enter
>   the IP addresses from which your key is to be accepted, one per line.
>   You may also enter a subnet using CIDR notation (e.g. 192.168.0.0/22).

Also you may come up with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318275/how-do-you-setup-the-referrers-for-a-google-maps-v3-key) after you set the referral, I think you'll find it useful.

Comment: but can't a malicious user spoof the referrer? the api security best practices at https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037 also says that " Publicly exposing your credentials can result in your account being compromised" and not to "embed API keys directly in code"

Comment: @Simon I think that by setting the referrers you're not exposing the API key to anyone, and the malicious user does not know which IPs are allowed so no spoofing can take place - but yeah, Imma edit the answer cuz there is need to keep it secret

Comment: Yes. The malicious user doesn't know which IPs are allowed but isn't it easy to guess? As an attacker, I would assume that the allowed IP is the IP of the server and I'd be right. This ip is easy to find unless there is a reverse proxy. Is google imply that we should be using reverse proxies?

Comment: Hmm... good thinking. I honestly don't know, but as you say it should relatively easy to get ahold of the referrer IP so the attacker could spoof it and make requests while bypassing this filter.

Answer (score 0):

Store the API in a text file. Then, use jQuery `$.get()` to retrieve it. Make sure the [configure your .htaccess file](http://www.ducea.com/2006/07/21/apache-tips-tricks-deny-access-to-certain-file-types/) to disallow direct TXT file access.

To load Google Maps API dynamically, use `$.getScript()` in your code, right before you need the map.

Google also recommends [restricting API usage by referral and/or IP address](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#apikeybestpractices).

Comment: While this might work, there is absolutely no reason to keep that key secret since, as you mentioned, you can configure it to be accepted only for your website(s). Also, OP didn't mention or tag the question with *jQuery* and therefore your answer might be of no help for him/her.

Comment: Google API documentation explicitly says: ["Do not embed API keys directly in code"](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#apikeybestpractices). Also, if OP can use an external API like Google Maps, I'm assuming he/she can use jQuery as well.